# How to distribute a console application?

Tags: c++, console

I am new to C++ and recently made a Tic-Tac-Toe game, which is a console application (no graphics). I have built my project in Release mode in Visual Studio 2019. I want this application to be transferred from one computer to another. I have zipped the Release folder of Visual Studio and tried to transfer it into another PC. When I ran it on another PC it failed to work?

I am new to programming, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t mention the exact error, but a first order possibility is a missing dependency.

Odds are you are missing the Visual Studio C++ runtime on the target machine (the one you are coping to). Windows does not install them by default, but Visual Studio does install them.

To download the runtime, go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ then navigate to “Other tools and frameworks” then “Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio“. Select the version that matches your build and download and install it. You can copy the runtime dlls over from your PC, but installing them is generally easier and better for maintenance. If you are using an older version of Visual Studio, the download is normally available, but you’ll have to search for it.

Failing that, you may have another dependency missing. You should look to tools such as Dependency Walker, still available here https://www.dependencywalker.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It must be run on pc's which OS you built on if it doesn't have additional libraries (Not Standart). if you have additional libraries, Add .dll files into release folder.

If you need help on customizing Console, I'll glad to help you on this.

Comment: I am running on same OS, how do I add dll (dynamic link library?) files ?

Comment: @FahimFuad just copy needed .dll files and paste it on folder which have your .exe file.